# Selecting from table into a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a (`bit` type) column named `Status` in `table1` which indicates to `0 = Stopped, 1 = Started` and there's a log table that has the `ID` of `table1`, the row existence indicates that the `Status` in `table1` is Damaged.

How can I create a `select` statement that covers the three statuses?
I was thinking of creating a temp table that has all the selected columns plus to a new column  (`NewStatus`) that gets it's value from `Status` column and a subselect statement that filter `table2` for the row ID in `table1`. But I can't imagine how I can do that!

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `left join`

```
select table1.*, 
   case when table2.id is null then 
        case table1.status 
        when 0 then 'stopped'
        when 1 then 'started'
        end
   else 'damaged'
   end
from
   table1 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

You could probably use `isnull` to obscure your intent which may or may not be faster.